# Are Roleplay Groups A Myth?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've heard that there are Roleplay groups in No Man's Sky that engage in battle, build, and/or explore.  I have seen articles on it from both polygon and reddit, but I do not know if any such groups exist anymore, or if they ever did.  I would like to try one out if I could.

So once and for all, are roleplay groups in No Man's Sky a myth?

Comment: Related Meta: [Does this constitute gaming history](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/does-talking-about-specific-game-groups-constitute-game-history)

Comment: Wow, bet you didn't expect such an uproar over a simple topic ;)

Comment: Nope. Haha. Oh well. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a myth.

---

It is clear that roleplay groups exist; and why wouldn't they? After all, a group is only defined as a number of people. If I personally wanted to engage in some roleplaying in *"No Man's Sky"*, I could very easily recruit any of my in-game friends. By its very definition, that would be a "role playing group".

Here are some examples:

- [Here is a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/luu1b6/no_mans_sky_rp_group/) for a group formed one month prior to this question being asked. They appear to have their own discord server.
- [Here is a FaceBook group](https://www.facebook.com/NMSRP/?ref=page_internal) that promote roleplaying and other adventure in *"No Man's Sky"*. They also advertise having their own discord server.
- [Here is a page at the *"No Man's Sky"* wiki](https://nomanssky.fandom.com/wiki/Circle16) that advertises a specific location built up by players to promote and facilitate roleplaying.
- As you say, yourself, [Polygon wrote an article](https://www.polygon.com/22412342/no-mans-sky-role-play-community-infestation-griefing-pvp-combat) on roleplayers and their impact on the game.

Given that I was able to find the above four solid references from googling "no man sky roleplay", amongst many other references of people discussing roleplaying, I think we can say without a doubt that roleplaying in *"No Man's Sky"* is not a myth.

If you were to ask if it is popular, or whether it still has an active community, that would both be an entirely different question and one that could easily fall outside of the scope of this site. I would consider the limitations of the game; console games only support a maximum of 8 players, though computer now supports up to 32 players.

---

As for where you would go to find said communities, again, this is an entirely different question and one that would be considered out of scope for this website. However, it seems you are already looking in the right place. I would recommend:

- [The *"No Man's Sky"* Reddit group](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/).
- [The *"No Man's Sky"* Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/NMSRP/?ref=page_internal).
- <del>[The Steam *"No Man's Sky"* forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/)</del> might put you in touch with other players, but be warned that I found numerous pages asking about roleplaying; almost all of the response was toxic.
- Recruit your friends! *"No Man's Sky"* is an impressive game - I've got friends into it that don't even like most other video games. The same goes for roleplaying - if you convince your group of friends to try a roleplaying session, you could easily find yourself so engaged that you make a weekly event out of it.